# how to nest query with avg and sum group by outer in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset like this:

```
tenant_code app_id reg_count
  1          1       0
  1          2       0
  2          1       1
  2          2       1
  3          1       5
  3          2       5
```

and now I want to group by `tenant_code` in the outer query and sum `reg_count`,but the `reg_count` should avg `app_id` in the inner query first and next sum `reg_count` in outer, what should I do to make it work? This is the query now I am using but did not work:

```sql
select
    sum(
        select avg(b.reg_count)
        from h_tenant_overview b
        where b.tenant_code = a.tenant_code
        group by b.tenant_code,b.app_id
    ) as reg_count
from h_tenant_overview a
group by tenant_code
```

the result should look like this if success:

```
tenant_code  reg_count
  1                 0
  2                 1
  3                 5
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define inner query, try this,

- added if condition in app_id count to prevent divisible by zero error

```sql
SELECT 
    tenant_code, 
    SUM(reg_count) AS sum_reg_count, 
    IF(COUNT(app_id) = 0, 0, SUM(reg_count) / COUNT(app_id)) AS avg_reg_count,
    IF(COUNT(app_id) = 0, 0, FLOOR(SUM(reg_count) / COUNT(app_id))) AS round_reg_count
FROM h_tenant_overview 
GROUP BY tenant_code
```

Output:

```
tenant_code | sum_reg_count | avg_reg_count | round_reg_count
1             1               0.5000          0
2             2               1.0000          1
3             10              5.0000          5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question since I can't figure out why you want to group by app_id. The following yields the expected result, see [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d7864e3599ae4765f6761e9a5aa82740)

```
select tenant_code, avg(reg_count)
from h_tenant_overview
group by tenant_code
```

or

```
select tenant_code, sum(reg_count) / nullif(count(reg_count),0)
from h_tenant_overview
group by tenant_code
```

The nullif in the last variant is unnecessary since `count(reg_count)` <> 0, but demonstrates a technique for handling division by zero.

Can you add sample data that does not return the expected result in fiddle and post back url, and I will have a look.